# Rake::TestTask Rails 5 Uninitialize Constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to break my tests into multiple test tasks:

```
Rails.configuration.use_database_cleaner = true

  namespace :test do
    Rails::TestTask.new(api: "test:prepare") do |t|
    t.pattern = 'test/api/**/*_test.rb'
  end

  task :jasmine_ci_in_another_process do
    if !system("./bin/rake jasmine:ci") 
      fail
    end
  end

  task :capybara_in_another_process do
    if !system("./bin/rake test:capybara")
      fail
    end
  end

  Rails::TestTask.new(capybara: [:prepare]) do |t|
    t.pattern = 'test/**/capybara/*_test.rb'
  end

  Rails::TestTask.new(unit: [:prepare]) do |t|
    t.test_files = FileList['test/**/*_test.rb'].exclude(
      'test/firebase/**/*_test.rb',
      'test/**/capybara/*_test.rb'
    )
  end

  task :ci => [:prepare, :jasmine_ci_in_another_process, :unit, :capybara_in_another_process]
 end

if !ENV['SKIP_JASMINE'] && ENV['TEST'].blank?
  Rake::Task[:test].enhance ['test:api', 'test:jasmine_ci_in_another_process']
end
```

Whenever I go to run the rake task whether it be `rake test` or `rake test:unit` etc. I keep getting an error stating the following: 
"NameError: uninitialized constant Rails::TestTask". If I have only one declaration of `Rails::TestTask.new` everything seems to be fine, but then my tests out broken out how I want them to be.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to replace Rails::TestTask with Rails::TestUnit::Runner.

I think this test of yours, for example:

```
Rails::TestTask.new(capybara: [:prepare]) do |t|
    t.pattern = 'test/**/capybara/*_test.rb'
end
```

will work in Rails 5.1 written like this:

```
require "rails/test_unit/runner"

namespace :test do
  task :capybara => "test:prepare" do
    $: << "test"
    test_files = FileList['test/**/capybara/*_test.rb']
    Rails::TestUnit::Runner.run(test_files)
  end
end
```

Tested in Rails 5.1.6

Credit should go to jonatack may 2015 post here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/19997

For rails 7:

```
namespace :test do
  task :capybara => "test:prepare" do
    if !Rails.env.test?
      system("rails test:capybara RAILS_ENV=test")
    else
      $: << "test"
      test_files = FileList['test/**/capybara/*_test.rb']
      Rails::TestUnit::Runner.run(test_files)
    end
  end
end
```

See also: [Run tests in custom test folder in Rails 5+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48465072/run-tests-in-custom-test-folder-in-rails-5)

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to Anatortoise House answer- for Rails 6.
This also includes excluding files.

```
# lib/tasks/test.rake
Rake::Task["test:system"].clear

namespace :test do
  desc "Run all system tests except test/serial folder"
  task system: "test:prepare" do
    $: << "test"
    test_files = FileList["test/system/**/*_test.rb"].exclude(
      "test/system/serial/**/*_test.rb"
    )
    Rails::TestUnit::Runner.run(test_files)
  end

  desc "Run all serial test folder"
  task serial: "test:prepare" do
    $: << "test"
    test_files = FileList["test/system/serial/*_test.rb"]
    Rails::TestUnit::Runner.run(test_files)
  end
end
```