# Run tests in custom test folder in Rails 5+

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

When I want to run all model tests we do

```
rails test:models
```

If I similarly would like to run tests that sits in a folder called `service_objects` (in the `test` folder) - what would be the required steps?

---

With inspiration from [multiple](https://github.com/metaskills/minitest-spec-rails/issues/49), [sources](https://medium.com/@Bakku1505/managing-separate-test-folders-in-rails-63f28ee7f1ae) I have tried the following in `lib/tasks`:

```
namespace :test do
  Rails::TestTask.new(classes: 'test:prepare') do |t|
    t.pattern = 'test/service_objects/**/*_test.rb'
  end
end
```

But running `rails test:service_objects` returns this error message:

> NameError: uninitialized constant Rails::TestTask

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace Rails::TestTask with Rails::TestUnit::Runner as shown in the file below, with the require path indicated at the top.

Then to run ONLY the tests in test/focused directory, you can call

```
rails test:focused
```

and to run ALL tests in the test directory EXCEPT those in test/long_running, you can call

```
rails test:without_long_running
```

Tested with Rails 5.1.6

The new Rails 5 test runner does have some really helpful features, but sometimes you still need a little more control.

```
# lib/tasks/test_tasks.rake

require "rails/test_unit/runner"

namespace :test do
  task :focused => "test:prepare" do
    $: << "test"
    test_files = FileList['test/focused/*_test.rb']
    Rails::TestUnit::Runner.run(test_files)
  end

  task :without_long_running_tests => "test:prepare" do
    $: << "test"
    test_files = FileList['test/**/*_test.rb'].exclude('test/long_running/**/*_test.rb')
    Rails::TestUnit::Runner.run(test_files)
  end
end
```

Credit should go to jonatack may 2015 post here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/19997

Update for Rails 7:

```
namespace :test do
  task :without_long_running_tests => "test:prepare" do
    if !Rails.env.test?
      system("rails test:without_long_running_tests RAILS_ENV=test")
    else
      $: << "test"
      test_files = FileList['test/**/*_test.rb'].exclude('test/long_running/**/*_test.rb')
      Rails::TestUnit::Runner.run(test_files)
    end
  end
end
```